# Extending jquery selector returns more data than it's supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extend jquery selector (for the first time) and I'm trying to get more readable and maintainable code for my friends which work with me on this project.

I'm trying to find all elements that have attribute `deletable=true` So when I look for those elements in firebug like this :

```
$('.wrapper[deletable="true"]')
```

I get correct result.

But when I try to shorten it to :

```
$(':deletable')
```

So I tried to extend the jquery selector like this :

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    deletable: function(el) {
      return $(el).find('[deletable="true"]').length > 0
    }
  });
```

For some reason I'm getting `html body mainContainer` in my result when I try `$(":deletable")` in firebug .. I also get deletable elements but I get these extra elements which I don't need like body/html elements.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what your custom selector is doing:

```
return $(el).find('[deletable="true"]').length > 0
```

Now, you're invoking your custom selector using `:deletable`. This is functionally equivalent to `*:deletable`. This means that you're selector is doing:

```
$('*').find('[deletable="true"]').length > 0
```

Which is finding all elements that contain an element with the attribute, including `body` and `html`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `find`, any element having a child matching the selector will return true. It seems you're trying to do this

```
return $(el).is('[deletable="true"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is finding all elements that have children that have the attribute `deletable="true"`.

Instead you can do:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    deletable: function(el) {
      return $(el).is('[deletable="true"]'); // Check if this element has the attribute
    }
  });
```

This will only return elements that have the attribute.

[<kbd>JSFiddle Example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/rzRqZ/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is saying body and html contain elements that have attribute `deletable=true`. I would check `attr` instead of using `find('[deletable="true"]).length` as this counts everything inside each DOM object.